# How can i update the location of user when the app is suspended

Tags: firebase, react-native, location

Am I able to get the users current location even if the app is killed or terminated? When users start walking, the location must be updated even if the app is killed or terminated.

Is it possible in react-native?

**Note:** I had done for foreground and background, but got stuck in case of the app is killed/suspended. Please I need more inputs for the same.

Comment: Your app can't do anything at all when its process is killed by the host OS.

Comment: To clarify, are you stating that you want a computer program, an app, to perform a function when its code is not running?

Answer (score 0):

For background and after a kill [Background Geolocation(@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation). Please refer below code

```js
BackgroundGeolocation.removeAllListeners();
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
  desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
  stationaryRadius: 50,
  distanceFilter: 50,
  notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
  notificationText: 'ENABLED',
  startForeground: false,
  notificationsEnabled: false,
  debug: false,
  startOnBoot: false,
  stopOnTerminate: true,
  locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
  interval: 1000,
  fastestInterval: 10000,
  activitiesInterval: 10000,
  stopOnStillActivity: false,
}, res => {
  BackgroundGeolocation.start();
  BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', async (location) => {
    BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know this works for background related things but my need is for when the app is killed or not in use.

Comment: If you want to listen for a specific time interval. You can use the silent notification to wake up the app for 30 seconds.